# Using commands in bluemix user interface

Tags: docker, command, containers, ibm-cloud

I need to use `docker container` in `bluemix` but my laptop does not support `docker` so I can't use the commands to run `docker` in `bluemix` using the CLI plug-ins.

Is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Why can't you run it on your laptop? Docker can run in some flavor on most operating systems (albeit within a VM on some).

You have a number of options though:

- Run it inside a linux virtual machine locally
- Run it inside a cloud linux virtual machine
- Run it inside a cloud container - Yes, you can actually run Docker inside a Docker container.
- Install a linux OS as a dual boot option on your laptop and run Docker there.

Edit: formatting

Answer (score 0):

which OS does your notebook run?
Docker supports Linux, OSX and Windows as well, and you could choose to use cf container plugin (cf ic), docker or also ice client.
Here you could find Bluemix documentation related to container